# Split a string in python based on a set of characters

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split a string based on some set of characters using python.
For example

```
String = "A==B AND B==C OR C!=A OR JP Bank==Chase"
```

I don't want to split the string based on space, since JP and Chase will form two different words.
So, I need to split based on ==,!=,AND,OR.
Expected output

```
[A,==,B,AND,B,==,C,OR,C,!=,A,OR,JP Bank,==,Chase]
```

Comment: Also one of the OR's!

Comment: @Manish why some OR's are removed and some are not?

Comment: Sorry , it was by mistake

Answer (score 3):

Using [**`re.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) with a capture group in your regular expression.

```
import re
s = "A==B AND B==C OR C!=A OR JP Bank==Chase"
pat = re.compile(r'(==|!=|AND|OR)')
pat.split(s)
```

**Result**

```
['A', '==', 'B ', 'AND', ' B', '==', 'C ', 'OR', ' C', '!=', 'A ', 'OR', ' JP Bank', '==', 'Chase']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try `re.split` function. `\s*` before and after `(AND|OR|[!=]=)` helps to remove the spaces also.

```
>>> s = "A==B AND B==C OR C!=A OR JP Bank==Chase"
>>> re.split('\s*(AND|OR|[!=]=)\s*', s)
['A', '==', 'B', 'AND', 'B', '==', 'C', 'OR', 'C', '!=', 'A', 'OR', 'JP Bank', '==', 'Chase']
```

Comment: Out of three almost the same answers, I find this solution the most complete in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
import re

inStrint = "A==B AND B==C OR C!=A OR JP Bank==Chase"
outList = re.split( '(==|!=|OR|AND)', inString)
outList = map( lambda x: x.strip(), outList)
```